# TSQL Count Consecutive records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping, partition

Suppose I have the following records:

```
KeyCol     ColA     ColB
------------------------
1          1        A
2          2        B
3          2        B
4          2        C
5          2        B
6          1        A
7          2        B
8          2        B
```

I Want to count consecutive records having the same values in ColA and ColB with this result

```
Col A      ColB     Start   Count
---------------------------------
1          A        1       1
2          B        2       2
2          C        4       1
2          B        5       1
1          A        6       1
2          B        7       2
```

There are plenty of similar questions on grouping and counting, but I fail to see how to translate it to this one. Especially many other examples don't have an explicit key column.

I Have tried to use the PARTITION function for counting the number of consecutive records and take it from there:

```
SELECT KeyCol, ColA, ColB
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (   PARTITION
                BY ColA, ColB
                ORDER BY KeyCol
            ) as RowNo
FROM MyTable
```

However, this produces this result:

```
KeyCol    Col A      ColB     RowNo
---------------------------------
1         1          A        1
2         2          B        1
3         2          B        2
4         2          C        1
5         2          B        3   (Needs to be 1)
6         1          A        2   (Needs to be 1)
7         2          B        4   (Needs to be 1)
8         2          B        5   (Needs to be 2)
```

As you can see, the row number increases for all same ColA,ColB, even if the records are not consecutive.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried something? If you have, edit the query into your question.

Comment: Hi TT, thanks for your comment. I just added a query I have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Gaps and Islands problem](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/). You need to use ranking functions to identify groups (islands) of the same value for ColB. The following query:

```
SELECT  KeyCol,
        ColA,
        ColB,
        GroupBy = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY KeyCol) - 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA, ColB ORDER BY KeyCol)
FROM    dbo.T
ORDER BY KeyCol;
```

You will get the output:

```
KeyCol     ColA     ColB    GroupBy
-----------------------------------------
1          1        A           0
2          2        B           1
3          2        B           1
4          2        C           3
5          2        B           2
6          1        A           4
7          2        B           3
8          2        B           3
```

As you can see, this identifies your islands, where two (or more) consecutive rows have the same values for ColA and ColB, you will get the same value in the column `GroupBy`.

Once you have this it is a simple case of grouping by it to get your required output. Giving a final query (with sample data) of:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (KeyCol INT, ColA INT, ColB CHAR(1));
INSERT @T (KeyCol, ColA, ColB)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A'), (2, 2, 'B'), (3, 2, 'B'), (4, 2, 'C'),
    (5, 2, 'B'), (6, 1, 'A'), (7, 2, 'B'), (8, 2, 'B');

WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  KeyCol,
            ColA,
            ColB,
            GroupBy = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY KeyCol) - 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA, ColB ORDER BY KeyCol)
    FROM    @T
)
SELECT  ColA, 
        ColB,
        Start = MIN(KeyCol),
        [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM    RankedData
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, GroupBy
ORDER BY Start;
```

Comment: Hi Gareth, great answer, thanks! I just have one question: can you make it work for the case where KeyCol has gaps it self. So say the third record start with KeyCol=4. This is the situation I am facing. Just curious, I can still use your answer by having an intermediate step where a table is created with consecutive KeyCol values.

Comment: @Roeland Sorry, I make that mistake all the time.... I have edited the answer so now instead of using `KeyCol - ROW_NUMBER()...` to generate the identifier, it now uses a further ranking function to generate a sequence without gaps to replace KeyCol.

Comment: It looks so simple now, having the answer at hand :) Thank you very much Gareth, couldn't dream of such a swift solution!!